# Is running object detection on Android using YOLO4 model possible at all?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit, yolov4

I've trained custom object detection model using YOLOv4. After successfully running inference using Python, I'm going to do it on Android device. So I convert it to TFLite 16bit quantization format. But when I load it using Tensorflow lite task vision library I keep getting error:

`'Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 3'`.

As I understand this error caused by the model not being compatible with the library's requirement. But since the number of output is specific to YOLOv4 model architecture, is this doable at all ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
SetNug

Comment: Check these requirements from the Task library
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/object_detector#supported_object_detector_models
If they do not suit you, you have to use plain Interpreter to make inferene on device.

Comment: Seems that's the only way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, But extremely slow inferencing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).